# My button isn't visible when I run the application

Tags: xcode, swift

Im trying to wirte an App with XCode for iPhones. I have some buttons with images but when I run my application on my phone I can't see the buttons. When I rotate my phone, the buttons appear for the duration of the rotation but afterwards they dissapear again. So I guess they're kind of here but not really...

I linked the buttons via @IBOutlet and it worked before I set the images and when I had only had text on them. I also fixed them with constraints in all four directions in the main storyboard.

At the very beginning, they're hidden, but later I set button.hidden=false. This shouldn't be a problem right?
This is where I make them visible:

```
@IBOutlet var buttonred: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var buttongreen: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var buttonyellow: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var buttonblue: UIButton!

@IBAction func startFastGame(sender: AnyObject) {
    if highscoretext.currentTitle=="fast 1"{
        buildColours();
        playNormalGame(1.0)
    }
}
func buildColours(){
    startbutton.hidden=true
    buttonred.hidden=false;
    buttongreen.hidden=false;
    buttonyellow.hidden=false;
    buttonblue.hidden=false;
}
func playNormalGame(howfast: Double){
    //here the game plays(this works)
}
```

Can anyone help me solving this issue?
Thanks

Comment: can you please post some code specially the one when you set hide to false ... It happens to me a lot of time an ussually it is a dispatch_getmainqueue issue

Comment: In most cases, you should not add constraints in all 4 directions

Comment: @Charon3000 We lack info, please provide more code.

Comment: Post  your storyboard or code for button constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't set 4 position constraints for a button.

You set one vertically and one horizontally.

Setting 4 position constraints can disrupt it's positioning.

If you did set 4 position constraints, consider removing two and tell us how that goes.

Comment: I tried this and I could indeed see the button, but it was located halfly off the screen. I could press it though

Comment: @Charon3000 That's because you have set bad constraints. I would recommend you read a tutorial on Autolayout :)

Comment: @Charon3000 Just remove all constraints, put your button in the middle of your VC and add a top 50 constraint and a leading constraint of 50.

Comment: Hi, here is a good auto layout tutorial for you https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2 :).

Comment: @Charon3000 That's an excellent tutorial ^ that Sultan Elerris posted here. Have a look :D

Comment: Great, now it works. The problem was with the constraints. Thank you guys very much;))

Comment: @Charon3000 Happy to help :D